# Use curl to download excel file

Tags: excel, curl, download

I have been given access to a url which I can happily use in a browser. It accepts a number of parameter, it sticks some of these parameters in an excel file and it dumps to my downloads directory an excel file without further intervention from the user.

I'd like to do all this through curl.

Is it possible?

The url looks something like this:

http://somesite.com/export?type=xlsx&object=container&reporttype=type01&id=11887&user=root

I'd like to maintain the name of the downloaded xlsx file as it gets constructed by the server.

Thanks for any help,

Joe

Answer (score 5):

Ok, adding -O -J (Use the header-provided filename, says curl help) does the trick. So the complete command line would be:

curl -O -J "http://somesite.com/export?type=xlsx&object=container&reporttype=type01&id=11887&user=root"

Thanks,

Joe